# How to run a logo on pageload

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have you ever used hotmail.com.
Once logged in you can see an outlook logo and loading bar and when done is disappears.

I am trying to do the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loadingDiv").show();
}

.loadingDiv{ width:100%; height:100% }
```

But I cannot understand when to hide it once the logo in fully animated.

the loadingDiv has a gif that shows my website logo being animated.

Comment: *Spashscreens* (logo) are very annoying as all they do is get in the users way for a few seconds so they can't get on.  For this, show the logo in the html then add a setTimeout to hide it.  A *loading* screen is of use as it will be there until the application is ready, in this case, show the logo in the html and then use document ready to load the other resources (ie they are not in the initial html).

Comment: This was very useful! I should make it like, if user clicks anywhere that logo disappears just like modal of twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```js
var $preLoader = $(".main-loader");
$(window).load(function() {
    $preLoader.fadeOut(""); // Animate loader off screen
});
```

```css
.main-loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif) center no-repeat white;
  background-size:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load()` method:

```
$(window).load(function(){// waits for all assets to load then executes the callback.
    $(".loadingDiv").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have `#loadingDiv` as the first page in a multipage app, so it opens by default. Then I run the following code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#home', { changeHash: false });
}, 2000);
```